# nHibernate: 2 relationships to and from same table inverting

Tags: c#, sql-server, nhibernate

I'm going to try to be as concise as possible. I have 2 tables:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Collections.Generic;

    namespace OperativeControl.Common.Entities
    {
        public class Question : BaseEntity
        {
            [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "description")]
            public virtual string Description { get; set; }
    
            [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "active")]
            public virtual bool Active { get; set; }
    
            [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "questionType")]
            public virtual QuestionType QuestionType { get; set; }
    
            [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "category")]
            public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
    
            [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "workcenterList")]
            public virtual IList<Workcenter> WorkcenterList { get; set; }
    
            [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "answerList")]
            public virtual IList<Answer> AnswerList { get; set; }
    
            [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "nextAnswerList")]
            public virtual IList<Answer> NextAnswerList { get; set; }
    
            [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "questionFieldList")]
            public virtual IList<QuestionField> QuestionFieldList { get; set; }
    
            [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "questionHistoricList")]
            public virtual IList<QuestionHistoric> QuestionHistoricList { get; set; }
    
            [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "triggerList")]
            public virtual IList<Trigger> TriggerList { get; set; }
    
            [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "mediaList")]
            public virtual IList<Media> MediaList { get; set; }
    
            //transient
            [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "questionHistoric")]
            public virtual QuestionHistoric QuestionHistoric { get; set; }
    
            public Question()
            {
                WorkcenterList = new List<Workcenter>();
                AnswerList = new List<Answer>();
                NextAnswerList = new List<Answer>();
                MediaList = new List<Media>();
                TriggerList = new List<Trigger>();
                QuestionHistoricList = new List<QuestionHistoric>();
            }
        }
    }
```

The mapping for that table:

```
using FluentNHibernate.Mapping;

namespace OperativeControl.Common.Entities.Mappings
{
    public class QuestionMap : ClassMap<Question>
    {
        public QuestionMap()
        {
            Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Identity();
            Map(x => x.Description);
            Map(x => x.Active);
            References(x => x.QuestionType).Column("fk_questiontype");
            References(x => x.Category).Column("fk_category");
            HasManyToMany(x => x.WorkcenterList)
               .Cascade.All()
               .Table("QuestionWorkcenter")
               .ParentKeyColumn("Fk_question")
               .ChildKeyColumn("Fk_workcenter");
            HasMany(x => x.AnswerList)
               .Inverse()
               .ForeignKeyConstraintName("FK_Question_Answer")
               .Cascade.All();
            HasMany(x => x.NextAnswerList)
               //.Inverse()
               .ForeignKeyConstraintName("FK_NextQuestion_Answer")
               .Cascade.All();
            HasMany(x => x.QuestionHistoricList)
               .Inverse()
               .Cascade.All();
            HasMany(x => x.QuestionFieldList)
               .Inverse()
               .Cascade.All();
            HasMany(x => x.TriggerList)
               .Inverse()
               .Cascade.All();
            HasMany(x => x.MediaList)
               //.Inverse()
               .Cascade.All();
            Table("Question");
        }
    }
}
```

And the second one, which has two FK to the first one

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace OperativeControl.Common.Entities
{
    public class Answer : BaseEntity
    {
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "name")]
        public virtual string Name { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "question")]
        public virtual Question Question { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "nextQuestion")]
        public virtual Question NextQuestion { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "questionHistoricList")]
        public virtual IList<QuestionHistoric> QuestionHistoricList { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "mediaList")]
        public virtual IList<Media> MediaList { get; set; }

        public Answer()
        {
            QuestionHistoricList = new List<QuestionHistoric>();
            MediaList = new List<Media>();
        }
    }
}
```

and it's mapping

```
using FluentNHibernate.Mapping;

namespace OperativeControl.Common.Entities.Mappings
{
    public class AnswerMap : ClassMap<Answer>
    {
        public AnswerMap()
        {
            Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Identity();
            Map(x => x.Name);
            References(x => x.Question).Column("Fk_question");
            References(x => x.NextQuestion).Column("Fk_nextquestion");
            HasMany(x => x.QuestionHistoricList)
               .Inverse()
               .Cascade.All();
            HasMany(x => x.MediaList)
               .Inverse()
               .Cascade.All();
            Table("Answer");
        }
    }
}
```

SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Answer](
    [Id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Fk_question] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [varchar](250) NOT NULL,
    [Fk_nextquestion] [bigint] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Answer] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Answer]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_NextQuestion_Answer] FOREIGN KEY([Fk_nextquestion])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Question] ([Id])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Answer] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_NextQuestion_Answer]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Answer]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Question_Answer] FOREIGN KEY([Fk_question])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Question] ([Id])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Answer] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Question_Answer]
GO
```

Now the issue: The next question relation can be null, but the question relationship cannot. I can persist to the DB and it all looks good, both in the answer of the DB and also inside the DB reading it with a query.

The lists are being inverted. The results that should be inside AnswerList, come in the NextAnswerList and viceversa

I've checked the mappings, I've checked the DB I have no idea of what it's happening.

I really hope it's something very tiny that I'm missing.

EDIT: Just to mention that the ForeignKeyConstraintName("FK_Question_Answer") is another unsuccessful attempt that I made. As you can see, I don't use that for the other HasMany's

EDIT 2: More info: If on the Mapping class of Question I comment out the HasMany related to NextAnswerList, the AnswerList is still empty; but if comment out AnswerList on the mapping, the NextAnswerList works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to fix the error. As mentioned, I tried mapping the FK with `ForeignKeyConstraintName("FK_Question_Answer")` unsuccessfully. I was able to make it work using `KeyColumns.Add("Fk_question")` I'm pretty sure there has to be something else, because with another project that also has this double relationships it is working perfectly.